# Unable to call TFS 2017 REST APIs

Tags: rest

When I connect to my on prem TFS server version 15.117.27414.0 using the url 
`GET http://{instance}/{collection}/{project}`, I get a `200 OK`  using Basic Authentication with Base64 of PAT.

However, when I make an API call on this url say `GET http://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=3.2`, I get a 404 error.

Request Header-

`Content-type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic ###########################`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct URI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/endpoints/endpoints?view=tfs-2017

The URI would be: 
`_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpoints`